# Copying one-dimensional array of formulas into a listobject column in Excel without auto-filling from first cell

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, listobject

Driving me a bit crazy. I have a list of formulas in an one-dimensional array that I want to copy into a column referred to by a listobject column header. However, when I try to copy the array of formulas in, Excel takes the first formula in the array and auto-fills it down. If I use a range that is off by one (e.g., fill all but the first cell, or all but the last cell) it doesn't autofill and uses the array formulas as expected. So, my current code that works is this:

```
    subtotalRange = tblSubtotalColLtr & tblSubtotalFirstRowRef & ":" & tblSubtotalColLtr & (tblSubtotalFirstRowRef + UBound(arrFormulas) - 2)
    finalRowRange = tblSubtotalColLtr & (tblSubtotalFirstRowRef + UBound(arrFormulas) - 1) & ":" & tblSubtotalColLtr & (tblSubtotalFirstRowRef + UBound(arrFormulas) - 1)
    Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False
    Range(subtotalRange).Formula = Application.Transpose(arrFormulas)
    Range(finalRowRange).Formula = arrFormulas(UBound(arrFormulas))
```

I was trying initially to just do this:

```
    Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False
    tbl.ListColumns(tbl.HeaderRowRange(AmountCol).Value).DataBodyRange.formula = application.transpose(arrFormulas)
```

The current code is super kludge-y - is there any way to make the second one work? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to resize the `DataBodyRange` to fit your Array.

> ```
> Application.AutoCorrect.AutoFillFormulasInLists = False
> tbl.ListColumns(AmountCol).DataBodyRange.Resize(UBound(arrFormulas) + 1).Formula = 
> Application.Transpose(arrFormulas)
> ```

Comment: Nope, that didn't work - same behavior as before with weird auto-fills.